# Installing credis via yum

Tags: yum

i do not want to manually install packages. i can't seem to find [credis](http://code.google.com/p/credis/) on yum. i have tried yum search all enablerepo=epel credis too, but it does not return anything i'd want here-

```
hiredis.i686 : A minimalistic C client library for Redis
hiredis.x86_64 : A minimalistic C client library for Redis
hiredis-devel.i686 : Header files and libraries for hiredis C development
hiredis-devel.x86_64 : Header files and libraries for hiredis C development
php-pecl-redis.x86_64 : Extension for communicating with the Redis key-value store
php-redis.x86_64 : Extension for communicating with the Redis key-value store
python-redis.noarch : A Python client for redis
php-nrk-Predis.noarch : PHP client library for Redis
redis.x86_64 : A persistent key-value database
autodownloader.noarch : GUI-tool to automate the download of certain files
ngspice.x86_64 : A mixed level/signal circuit simulator
perl-Class-C3-Adopt-NEXT.noarch : Reduce one's dependency on NEXT
python-celery.noarch : Distributed Task Queue
rubygem-moneta.noarch : A unified interface to key/value stores
```

Comment: You might want to mention which distribution you're using. Is it Red Hat, CentOS or Fedora? Try rpmfind.net too.

Comment: Amazon Linux AMI 2013.09.1 - ami-83e4bcea (64-bit). rpmfind has nothing.